# React TypeScript prevent element having children of unexpected type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to prevent a react component having at least (one or more) children of a specific type.

This script works, but it allows the component having other types of children, except primitive ones:

```js
import * as React    from "react"

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            {/* Should compile, it does: OK! */}
            <Foo><Bar lorem={0} /></Foo>

            {/* Should compile, it does: OK! */}
            <Foo>
                <Bar lorem={1} />
                <Bar lorem={2} />
            </Foo>

            {/* Should not compile, it does not: OK! */}
            <Foo />

            {/* Should not compile, it does: NOT OK... */}
            <Foo><div /></Foo>

            {/* Should not compile, it does: NOT OK... */}
            <Foo>
                <div />
                <div />
            </Foo>
        </div>
    }
}

class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {
  render() {
    return <ul>{this.props.children}</ul>
  }
}

interface FooProps {
    children: React.ReactElement<BarProps> | React.ReactElement<BarProps>[]
}

class Bar extends React.Component<BarProps> {
    render() {
        return <li>{this.props.lorem}</li>
    }
}

interface BarProps {
    lorem: number
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code ?

You can download a Git short project [here](https://github.com/calcimicium-needing-help/react-typescript-children-typechecking) to try it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you cannot retrieve type information from `JSX.Element`

> **[The JSX result type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)**
>   By default the result of a JSX expression is typed as any. You can customize the type by specifying the JSX.Element interface. However, it is not possible to retrieve type information about the element, attributes or children of the JSX from this interface. It is a black box.

By overriding `children` type definition you can limit the type to `string` for example or single `JSX.Element`, any custom component will be 'casted' to `JSX.Element` and its type is not accessible.

[The JSX result type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Comment: So, do I have to check at runtime whether the children are from a particular type and throw an error otherwise ?

Comment: Yes theoretically you can get children as array `React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)` cast on of them to `React.ReactElement` and the validate `.type`